# javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, path, environment-variables, command-prompt, javac

I am experiencing an error while trying to compile Java programs.

I am on Windows (this is a Windows-specific problem) and I have the latest JDK installed.

I have attempted a solution involving the `PATH` variable, but the error persists.

Console output:

```
C:\>set path=C:Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin
C:\>javac Hello.java
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: i think your path is not set . go to your enviromentvariable and set path their

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is easily findable in the [actual JDK installation instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html) and the answer there is up to date and of higher quality than any answer here. It is also readily available, for all platforms, in the first chapter of the [official getting started tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html).

Comment: Ta for the information Jason C. But I confess I find the decision to call this thread off-topic appears to be odds with the number of others that have upticked this answer. As I am about to do.

Comment: Current link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#BABGDJFH

Comment: Adding a new variable is easier and once you create a new variable "PATH" make sure you add semicolon (;) and the end of the value.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html

Comment: You can find everything from java download to execution of sample java program [here](http://techtopicsbyme.blogspot.com/2016/06/java-environment-setup.html)

Comment: You missed the backslash after C and you need to add semicolon at the end of the path. This is the result after playing around with the semicolon which is very important

Comment: I have the exact same problem! I have reinstalled the programs, set the paths of jre and jdk again, I run "java" and I get all details that Java is installed, but when I run "javac", I get this error.. I have tried everything! Please help

Answer (score 538):

## TL;DR

For experienced readers:

1. Find the Java path; it looks like this: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdkxxxx\bin\`
2. Start-menu search for "environment variable" to open the options dialog.
3. Examine `PATH`. Remove old Java paths.
4. Add the new Java path to `PATH`.
5. Edit `JAVA_HOME`.
6. Close and re-open console/IDE.

---

Welcome!

You have encountered one of the most notorious technical issues facing Java beginners: the `'xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command...` error message.

In a nutshell, **you have not installed Java correctly**. Finalizing the installation of Java on Windows requires some manual steps. You must always perform these steps after installing Java, including after upgrading the JDK.

## Environment variables and `PATH`

*(If you already understand this, feel free to skip the next three sections.)*

When you run `javac HelloWorld.java`, cmd must determine where `javac.exe` is located. This is accomplished with `PATH`, an environment variable.

An [*environment variable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) is a special key-value pair (e.g. `windir=C:\WINDOWS`). Most came with the operating system, and some are required for proper system functioning. A list of them is passed to every program (including cmd) when it starts. [On Windows](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html), there are [two types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477660/what-is-the-difference-between-user-variables-and-system-variables): *user environment variables* and *system environment variables*.

You can see your environment variables like this:

```
C:\>set
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\craig\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
...
```

The most important variable is [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). It is a list of paths, separated by `;`. When a command is entered into cmd, each directory in the list will be scanned for a matching executable.

On my computer, `PATH` is:

```
C:\>echo %PATH%
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPower
Shell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs;C:\Users\craig\AppData\
Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs;C:\msys64\usr\bin;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\
msys64\mingw32\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Users\
craig\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin;C:\ProgramFiles\Git\cmd;
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;C:\Program Files\7-Zip\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\
Program Files\launch4j;C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
\Adobe\AGL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
(x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS
Client\;C:\Users\craig\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

When you run `javac HelloWorld.java`, cmd, upon realizing that `javac` is not an [internal command](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html), searches the [system `PATH` followed by the user `PATH`](https://superuser.com/questions/867728/user-vs-system-environment-variables-do-system-variables-override-user-variabl). It mechanically enters every directory in the list, and checks if [`javac.com`, `javac.exe`, `javac.bat`, etc.](https://www.nextofwindows.com/what-is-pathext-environment-variable-in-windows) is present. When it finds `javac`, it runs it. When it does not, it prints `'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

You must add the Java executables directory to `PATH`.

## JDK vs. JRE

*(If you already understand this, feel free to skip this section.)*

When downloading Java, you are offered a choice between:

- The [Java Runtime Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine#Java_Runtime_Environment) (JRE), which includes the necessary tools to run Java programs, but *not* to compile new ones – it contains `java` but not `javac`.
- The [Java Development Kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) (JDK), which contains both `java` and `javac`, along with a host of other development tools. The JDK is a superset of the JRE.

You must make sure **you have installed the JDK**. If you have only installed the JRE, you cannot execute `javac` because you do not have an installation of the Java compiler on your hard drive. Check your Windows programs list, and make sure the Java package's name includes the words "Development Kit" in it.

## Don't use `set`

*(If you weren't planning to anyway, feel free to skip this section.)*

Several other answers recommend executing some variation of:

```
C:\>:: DON'T DO THIS
C:\>set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin
```

Do not do that. There are several major problems with that command:

1. This command **erases everything else** from `PATH` and replaces it with the Java path. After executing this command, you might find various other commands not working.
2. Your Java path **is probably not** `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin` – you almost definitely have a newer version of the JDK, which would have a different path.
3. The new `PATH` **only applies** to the current cmd session. You will have to reenter the `set` command every time you open Command Prompt.

Points #1 and #2 can be solved with this slightly better version:

```
C:\>:: DON'T DO THIS EITHER
C:\>set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\<enter the correct Java folder here>\bin;%PATH%
```

But it is just a bad idea in general.

## Find the Java path

The right way begins with finding where you have installed Java. This depends on *how* you have installed Java.

#### Exe installer

You have installed Java by running a setup program. Oracle's installer places versions of Java  under `C:\Program Files\Java\` (or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\`). With File Explorer or Command Prompt, navigate to that directory.

Each subfolder represents a version of Java. If there is only one, you have found it. Otherwise, choose the one that looks like the newer version. Make sure the folder name begins with `jdk` (as opposed to `jre`). Enter the directory.

Then enter the `bin` directory of that.

You are now in the correct directory. Copy the path. If in File Explorer, click the address bar. If in Command Prompt, [copy](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25590/how-to-enable-ctrlv-for-pasting-in-the-windows-command-prompt/) the prompt.

The resulting Java path should be in the form of (without quotes):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdkxxxx\bin\
```

#### Zip file

You have downloaded a .zip containing the JDK. Extract it to some random place where it won't get in your way; `C:\Java\` is an acceptable choice.

Then locate the `bin` folder somewhere within it.

You are now in the correct directory. Copy its path. This is the Java path.

Remember to never move the folder, as that would invalidate the path.

## Open the settings dialog

[image]

That is the dialog to edit `PATH`. There are numerous ways to get to that dialog, depending on your Windows version, UI settings, and how messed up your system configuration is.

Try some of these:

- Start Menu/taskbar search box » search for "environment variable"
- Win + R » `control sysdm.cpl,,3`
- Win + R » `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` » Environment Variables
- File Explorer » type into address bar `Control Panel\System and Security\System` » Advanced System Settings (far left, in sidebar) » Environment Variables
- Desktop » right-click This PC » Properties » Advanced System Settings » Environment Variables
- Start Menu » right-click Computer » Properties » Advanced System Settings » Environment Variables
- Control Panel (icon mode) » System » Advanced System Settings » Environment Variables
- Control Panel (category mode) » System and Security » System » Advanced System Settings » Environment Variables
- Desktop » right-click My Computer » Advanced » Environment Variables
- Control Panel » System » Advanced » Environment Variables

Any of these should take you to the right settings dialog.

If you are on Windows 10, Microsoft has blessed you with a [fancy new UI](https://betanews.com/2015/11/23/windows-10-finally-adds-a-new-path-editor/) to edit `PATH`. Otherwise, you will see `PATH` in its full semicolon-encrusted glory, squeezed into a single-line textbox. Do your best to make the necessary edits without breaking your system.

## Clean `PATH`

Look at `PATH`. You almost definitely have two `PATH` variables (because of user vs. system environment variables).  You need to look at both of them.

Check for **other Java paths** and remove them. Their existence can cause all sorts of conflicts. (For instance, if you have JRE 8 and JDK 11 in `PATH`, in that order, then `javac` will invoke the Java 11 compiler, which will create version 55 `.class` files, but `java` will invoke the Java 8 JVM, which only supports up to version 52, and you will experience [unsupported version errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi) and not be able to compile and run any programs.) Sidestep these problems by making sure you only have one Java path in `PATH`. And while you're at it, you may as well [uninstall old Java versions](https://java.com/en/download/faq/remove_olderversions.xml), too. And remember that you [don't need to have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988601/do-i-need-both-jdk-and-jre) both a JDK and a JRE.

If you have `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`, **remove that as well**. Oracle intended to solve the problem of Java paths breaking after upgrades by creating a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) that would always point to the latest Java installation. Unfortunately, it often ends up pointing to the wrong location or [simply not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864662/how-to-solve-the-error-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-c-programdata-oracle-ja). It is better to remove this entry and manually manage the Java path.

Now is also a good opportunity to perform general housekeeping on `PATH`. If you have paths relating to software no longer installed on your PC, you can remove them. You can also shuffle the order of paths around (if you care about things like that).

## Add to `PATH`

Now take the Java path you found three steps ago, and place it in the system `PATH`.

It shouldn't matter where in the list your new path goes; placing it at the end is a fine choice.

If you are using the pre-Windows 10 UI, make sure you have placed the semicolons correctly. There should be exactly one separating every path in the list.

There really isn't much else to say here. Simply add the path to `PATH` and click OK.

## Set `JAVA_HOME`

While you're at it, you may as well set `JAVA_HOME` as well. This is another environment variable that should also contain the Java path. Many Java and non-Java programs, including the popular Java build systems [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and [Gradle](https://gradle.org/), will throw errors if it is not correctly set.

If `JAVA_HOME` does not exist, create it as a new system environment variable. Set it to the path of the Java directory without the `bin/` directory, i.e. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdkxxxx\`.

Remember to edit `JAVA_HOME` after upgrading Java, too.

## Close and re-open Command Prompt

Though you have modified `PATH`, all running programs, including cmd, only see the old `PATH`. This is because the list of all environment variables is only copied into a program when it begins executing; thereafter, it only consults the cached copy.

There is no good way to [refresh cmd's environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in-w), so simply close Command Prompt and open it again. If you are using an IDE, close and re-open it too.

## See also

- [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)
- [How do I set or change the PATH system variable?](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)
- [How to set the path and environment variables in Windows](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)
- [How to set Path environment variables in Windows 10](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/set-path-environment-variables-in-windows-10/)

Comment: This worked for me, but before I had tried to add the location at the end of the Path string.  Why does it only work at the beginning?

Comment: Thanks! this works for me! 
@Eric H: Adding at the end works for me. From what I understand, it goes through Path from left to right and look for javac.exe. So maybe you have it in some directory that in the front and that javac.exe does not work.

Comment: +1 for closing the command-line then re-opening it, that worked for me!

Comment: Does it make sense if I have different version of jdk and jre on my computer?

Comment: I learned a lot of things about the OS system while setting up these variables and all that. thanks man

Comment: You deserve a medal for this.

Comment: For me, adding the location to the system Path wasn't enough; I *also* had to add it to my user Path as well.

Comment: lol can't believe this actually worked. I really expected to go through this long tutorial for everything to not work. Thank you so much lmaoo

Comment: What do I do if javac is still not recognized?

Answer (score 78):

try this.. 
I had it too but now it solved in XP..

```
C:\ YourFolder >set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;
C:\ YourFolder >javac YourCode.java
```

Answer (score 48):

You mistyped the `set` command – you missed the backslash after `C:`. It should be:

```
C:\>set path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin
```

Comment: I missed that right but that was my typographical error when posting my concern here.  I did check it and everything is correctly spelled but still gives me the same error.

Comment: @user987137. Evidently, something is incorrect.  Is JDK (mind you - JDK not JRE) installed in the specified location - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0`? If so, what happens if you do `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin` and then `javac -version`?

Comment: I had the same error when setting up JDK on Win XP even though I had the correct path set. Simply closing the command prompt and opening it again fixed it.

Comment: @ChrisJ - This is because the new command prompt will be started in a new session and therefore also load the updated environmental variables.

Answer (score 19):

Run the following from the command prompt for the version of Java you have installed:

```
set Path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin"
```

or

```
set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin"
```

I have tried this and it works well.

Comment: This is not recommended as it overrides all other PATH options

Answer (score 6):

If java command is working and getting problem with javac. then first check in jdk's bin directory javac.exe file is there or not.
If javac.exe file is exist then set `JAVA_HOME` as System variable.

Answer (score 3):

Check your environment variables.

In my case I had JAVA_HOME set in the **System variables** as well as in my **User Account** variables and the latter was set to a **wrong version of Java**. I also had the same problem with the Path variable.

After **deleting JAVA_HOME from my User Account** variables and removing the wrong path from the Path variable it worked correctly.