# Can't find Typescript compiler: Command "tsc" is not valid

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, typescript, tsc

Just installed Typescript extension to VS2012 and followed [Install TypeScript for Visual Studio 2012](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=266563) and then the [tutorial](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Tutorial/) to call the compiler:

```
> tsc greeter.ts
```

But when i try to compile .ts file where should i type: `tsc greeter.ts`? Tried it in VS command line and in windows console, always get the message that tsc is not recognized as command(`Command "tsc" is not valid.`).

Comment: how do you try to compile? at the commandline or via the GUI?

Comment: possible duplicate of: [javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Comment: @hakre, how can this be a duplicate?..Answer is about .NET SDK!

Comment: To call a command on a system, you either need to specify the full path of it or the commands hosting directory is part of the path variable. This is actually identical, only the command differs. However I'd say that this mental action of correlation should be possible for a common programmer.

Comment: @user11201714 sorry? The question is 6 years old, also it's NOT about installing typescript.

Comment: @hakre just revised the question, I've to apologize: sure you were right, this one was the same problem, just for other executable. Still here is a valuable expanded answer for new ones: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40616601/47672 so probably this question+answer has some value.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Ensure you have,

> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0`

or,

> `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0`

on your path. If not, try restarting `CMD.EXE` and see if shows up with a fresh copy. If that fails, try adding one of the above manually to your path.

Comment: Nice! Ive the path (x86), tho its x64 windows..Thank you!

Comment: How do I add it to Path? I tried it myself, but it still doesn't work. Maybe I did it wrong? I added "tsc" and "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0" to PATH but VS CMD still won't see it as being there. Also, VS CMD doesn't recognise **anything**.

Comment: Try changing the name of the path variable to PATH : Or create another with the uppercase name, instead of renaming)

Comment: http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path

Comment: I have installed typescript using 'npm install -g typescript' command  but I don't find above path's in my Windows 8.1 Pro machine to set the path.

Comment: In Windows 10, search for *Edit the System Environment Variables* in Windows search and press the *Environment Variables...* button. Under *System Variables* select *Path* and press *Edit*. Use *New* to add a new path, and delete any old typescript entries (if applicable).

Comment: Good lord! life saver!

Comment: Was having this problem in my IDE terminal from which I had just run `npm install typescript`  Restarting the terminal updated the path for me and all worked.

Answer (score 99):

If you're using tsc as a node module, make sure you've installed it with

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Then it should be available globally in your node command prompt

Comment: I didn't install the node/npm module and can access it. Currently I'm not sure whether it comes with VS 2012 or the TypeScript plugin.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 has no out-of-the-box support for typescript, but the plugin installs the compiler. This download page https://typescript.codeplex.com/releases/view/111080 says that you can install typescript with "An MSI containing tools for Visual Studio, plus the compiler" . If you can access the compiler from your cmd but haven't installed the node module globally, then the Typescript plugin has installed the compiler and added it to your path.

Comment: If you have installed tsc as a node module, you can also use `npm list -global --depth=0` to check, if it was installed globally and successfully.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one. It should solve the same issue regardless of platform or editor software.

Comment: Where is tsc supposed to be?  I installed as indicated, I restarted the command prompt but tsc isn't recognized.  Am I missing a path entry or am I missing tsc.exe (or similar)

Comment: If on windows, there is a special node command prompt. Could you try that one ?

Comment: Why would we want to install globally?  Then how do we know it's using the right version?

Comment: Yes and no: this is NOT the best answer as it answers the case when NPM is installed (the answer even states that "if your're using tsc as node module..."). Sure there are people without NPM installed. The problem was that prompt could not find the tsc executable. Editing the PATH env sure helps even if you just copy tsc (or any other executable you have similar problem with) without doing any additional installation registrations and that's it. The marked as answer answer is sure NOT the best too, but historically it was the first one that resolved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 16):

For folks on **Windows** with **Visual Studio Code**, who don't want to install full Visual Studio just for `tsc.exe`, I can suggest to simply download it from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593.

This is a shame that this link is missing from the TypeScript download page.

Although the installer is called `TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015`, it works with Visual Studio Code as well.

After you downloaded and installed TypeScript, you should manually add its installation directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.0\` in my case) to the `%PATH%` [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

Open environment variables editor:

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>; <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd>, <kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>; click **Edit environment variables for your account**.

In the window opened find `Path` user variable (note that it is not named `%PATH%` here, but still this is it). You probably have some path set there already. You just have to type `;`, **append** the TypeScript install location and add one more `;` in the end.

Screenshot for your reference:

[image]

After this is done, open Command Prompt and type in `tsc -v`. If `tsc.exe`'s version is getting displayed, you're done. For this to work, **restart Command Prompt and VS Code** after making the change to the `%PATH%`.

P.S. If you get "error TS5057: Cannot find a tsconfig.json file at the specified directory: '.'", just create `tsconfig.json` file in the document root (that's probably where your `.ts` files are) with simple contents: `{}`. This means "an empty JSON file <...>. This will be sufficient for most people." ([source](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md#basic)).

Comment: "For this to work, restart Command Prompt"  Glad you added that point.  Thats why it didnt work for me.

Comment: go to edit environment variable for your account and add following

Before "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\" add => "%AppData%\npm".   Close command prompt, vs code and re-open again

Comment: @Vaibhav this implies you have `npm` installed. My answer is more generic and doesn't require any dependencies apart from the `tsc.exe` itself.

Comment: This is a lifesaver answer, @Neurotransmitter - thank you. I've spent all evening trying to get Visual Studio Code to "see" and run `tsc` and of all the things that I've tried, this is the _first_ process that has worked. (In my case, the installation folder was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.2\ ` but, apart from that, I followed your detailed and excellent instructions to the letter - thank you!)

Comment: Update: It seems what I wanted to achieve - installing Visual Studio Code and TypeScript but _without_ having to install Node.js 13.4.0 (the last Node.js compatible with Windows 7) - wasn't possible in the end. Nevertheless, thanks, @Neurotransmitter, for saving me from tearing all of my hair out at a point in my VSC+TS discovery process where literally nothing seemed to be working.

Comment: I installed it using the given link, but there does not seem to be a tsc.exe included in the installation.

Comment: @GonenI tsc.exe should be installed at ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\*```.

Comment: @Neurotransmitter It wasn't in my case. While the directory and its subfolders were created and contain many .js files and dlls, there was no tsc.exe to befound. Perhaps they decided to no longer include it in the installations.

Answer (score 6):

If you have installed typescript for a specific folder/project i.e. not globally,then you can should use **tsc** command with **npx**
e.g

```
npx tsc myfile.ts
```

npx is used to excute a package .

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes closing and reopening the command prompt solves the issue.

This is due to that fact that the location of the binary (in this case tsc) is not yet available in the PATH, hence tsc doesn't link to /usr/bin/tsc.

Answer (score 2):

Check both of these folders to find out what TypeScript version you have:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\
```

Right-click the folder showing the version number then 'copy as path'.

Paste this into your system path (quick access - Windows key then type 'env'). Then open a new command prompt console as administrator and 'tsc' should work.

Comment: Is there a better way to get the path to `tsc.exe` instead of assuming it's `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\{version}\tsc.exe`? And how do we determine what the version number is? Is there some registry value we can use?

Answer (score 1):

As new path variable, don't use the displayed `tsc version` number but the TypeScript Folder Name which is different.

Sample :

```
tsc -v display 2.4.1
```

but TypeScript directory is

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.4

Answer (score 1):

Just delete AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1 file and the issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I did install typescript globally by using `-g` flag but `tsc` was not recognized.
It turns out that below directory was not included in `path` environment variable:

```
C:\Users\Jitendra\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Adding this directory to `path` variable worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In windows and npm new version, If `tsc --v` is error `'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` should be add npm path to env windows as follows:

1- open env (Edit the system environment variables).

2- Clicking the `Advance` tab.

3- `Environment Variables` button click.

4- In System variables click `Path` in its list.

5- Clicking `New` button and app `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm`, that you should change the  to your windows user.

6- Clicking `OK`, and clicking `OK` buttons of other windows.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have on your system's path's

```
C:\Users\"Your username"\AppData\Local\Programs\MicrosoftVsCode\bin
```

Change "your username" with your actual username

Answer (score 0):

In CMD type `where tsc` if it doesn't show a path like this `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\typescript version you installed\` it means your tsc is not running from here.You need to change the environment path manually by following `@TranslucentCloud` 's answer .

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following path
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm`
to the PATH variable. Notice that you should change the  to your windows user.
This will work like a charm. Cheers!!

Comment: Yes, but not quite right: the question is not about npm, it's about typescript compiler. So the right answer is: there should be ```tsc``` executable's directory path in PATH env variable. And ```tsc``` can be not in NPM-s directory. I can have TypeScript without NPM and still use the command line. See the answers above they are right about that. Also: try not to answer already answered questions with the "same" answer (yeah you mentioned NPM instead of ts, but the "core" is same: PATH env), you will just create more confusion for the person who is reading about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

**npx tsc greeter.ts**

I was getting the same error until i tried this.