# Trying (and failing) to run the (successfully installed) TypeScript Compiler in Visual Studio Code using tsc in VSC Terminal

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsc

I appreciate that this is likely a naive question, however I am trying to find my way in the dark and the documentation from Microsoft really isn't as intuitive as I need it to be, since I've never worked with either **Visual Studio Code** or **TypeScript** before.

- I have installed **Visual Studio Code** (version 1.51.1)
- `Visual Studio Code > Help > About` references **Node.js 12.14.1** - I'm not sure if it's telling me that it has included that in its own install or if it needs that to work properly
- I have downloaded **TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015** (from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) and successfully installed it by following [the excellent and clear instructions from @Neurotransmitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685995/cant-find-typescript-compiler-command-tsc-is-not-valid#answer-40616601)

I have written and saved a basic `.ts` file:

```
// my-first-typescript.ts

const myConst: number = 22;
console.log(myConst / 2);
```

If I now run `Visual Studio Code > Terminal > New Terminal` and I enter:

```
tsc my-first-typescript.ts
```

a console pops up on **Windows 7** asking:

> Choose the program you want to use to open this file

Obviously the Terminal is trying to open `tsc.js` and it doesn't know how.

This is where I'm stuck.

Is there any way to execute `tsc.js` without having `Node.js` installed? (I'm guessing not?)

But then, hasn't **Visual Studio Code** already installed itself with `Node.js`? (If not, what's the **Node.js 12.14.1** it refers to?)

I'm trying as much as possible to avoid downloading and installing `Node.js` and `npm`.

If I absolutely have to, then I will.

But it's a lot to download just to be able to run the **TypeScript Compiler** (`tsc`) in **Visual Studio Code**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install typescript into your environment. And yes you need [node installed](https://nodejs.org/).

After install node/npm you [can install typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/#installation) with

```
npm install -g typescript
```

After that you can call the compiler `tsc`, That will just convert the file from `.ts` to `.js`

If you want to run it, I recommend to install [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node)

then you can do

```
ts-node myFile.ts
```

Comment: Thank you, @distante. So what's the reference in `Visual Studio Code > Help > About` to **Node.js 12.14.1**? Is it saying that's the version of `Node.js` it already recognises on my computer? Or is it saying that's the (optimal) version of `Node.js` it needs?

Comment: @Rounin to be honest I am not 100% sure. But  I think it refers to the internal node compilation that VsSode uses (it is an javascript/electron/node App). Because I have node 12.13 installed but I also get 12.14.1 in VsCode.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, @distante. That suggests that whatever VSCode is referring to, it isn't related to any version of `node` already installed locally.

Comment: @Rounin Help -> About shows the internal Node.js version used by VS Code, which is an Electron app. Electron comes bundled with its own node version.

Comment: Many thanks, again, @distante - I finally got there. And, believe it or not, the single most important sentence for me in your answer was: _"And yes you need node installed."_ because I spent hours yesterday, trying to get Visual Studio Code & TypeScript running while avoiding at all costs installing `node.js` and `npm`.

Comment: No problem @Rounin we all are beginners with some technology, library or API :D