# Java windows command

Tags: path, java

I am trying to compile some java code on Windows 7 pc, I have installed java JDK and I am trying to use  the `javac` command in cmd but I get output saying that

`'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

What do I have to do to enable compiler in cmd or is it possible to do in Windows?

Comment: Either add the path where your `javac` executable resides to your `%PATH%` environment or use the absolute path to `javac` for executing it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Go to properties by  **right click** on icon Computer , then navigate to  **Advanced System Settings**.

2)Click **Environment Variables**.

3)Click on New , set **Variable name** as **path** and **Variable path** as the path of java **jdk installation directory** which could be something like this -

> **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin**;

where **C:** is the drive where JDK is installed and **Program Files\java** is the directory where it resides.

look out for **semi-colon(;)** at the last.

4)Click ok

5)Restart cmd and run javac , it should work now.

Look for [**Screenshots**](http://vietpad.sourceforge.net/javaonwindows.html) here for more help.

Regards

Anshul

Comment: Why is this not added through installation of JDK?

Comment: Did it work..?? , i dont know why it didnt happened , may be Oracle guys are lazy enough to code that , there was a time when JAVA used be under SUN , and it was shining , but now Oracle has ruined the rep of JAVA :/

Comment: Yes It worked and since this looks like be best answer I will accept it

Comment: Thank You :)   happy java coding  !!

Answer (score 0):

you have to set a new system variable for your JAVA_HOME in windows.
See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Add the path to `bin` folder of `JDK` in your `PATH` variable. For instructions to set `PATH` variable follow this [tutorial](http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Your java directory is not on the path. Here are some helpful screenshots to show how to set it up:
http://vietpad.sourceforge.net/javaonwindows.html