# Error in setting JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, maven, installation, path-variables

I have recently downloaded Maven and followed the instructions given on this [this](http://www.example.com/) page. I already have ant installed on my machine.
Now, if I want to verify that Maven is installed perfectly or not it is giving me error that JAVA_HOME is not set correctly, but same works perfectly fine for ANT.

```
For Maven I tried :
1. open cmd
2. type mvn -version
3. Error appeared :
C:\Users\Admin>mvn -version

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin"
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation

For ANT I tried and worked :
1. open cmd
2. type mvn -version
3. Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.1 compiled on May 15 2013
```

I went to the directory to check that java.exe is actually there in that directory or not and it was there. I checked the environment variables they set fine. I restarted the system and checked again but same problem. Please let me know what am I missing.

Comment: Set valid JAVA_HOME path in System environment

Comment: try this.. `C:\ YourFolder >set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;`, in this case, my jdk version is `1.7.0_09` **OR** you can looked out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or/16562626#16562626). Welcome to [StackOverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/).. ^^

Comment: With Maven, your JAVA_HOME must NOT CONTAIN the "bin", just ...\jdk1.7.0_09\ is enough.

Comment: If you did everything correctly and it still doesn't work, try **restarting** your machine

Answer (score 89, accepted):

JAVA_HOME should point to jdk directory and not to jre directory. Also JAVA_HOME should point to the home jdk directory and not to jdk/bin directory.

Assuming that you have JDK installed in your program files directory then you need to set the JAVA_HOME like this:

```
JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdkxxx"
```

xxx is the jdk version

Follow this link to learn more about setting JAVA_HOME:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html

Comment: Thanks Juned it worked , but why jdk not jre...and why ant was working and maven wasn't.

Comment: thanks, it's worked! For OSX path we can read here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: This worked for me https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 17):

Do not include bin in your JAVA_HOME env variable

Answer (score 9):

Follow the instruction in [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/).

`JAVA_HOME`should be like this

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
```

Comment: Does it require quotes around the path?

Answer (score 7):

**JAVA_HOME** should point to jdk directory like in the image with new variable, like below

[image: JAVA_HOME]

**PATH** should point to jdk bin like below

[image: PATH]

Comment: thanks! this needs to be at the top

Comment: The only guy that I found in the internet that said how exactly to do this... The variable points to the root jdk path since the Path should include the binaries directory... Insane. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk(JDK version number)

Example: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10

And then restart you command prompt it works.

Comment: thank you for this. been struggling for hours with this until i read the restart part. don't forget to restart, cuz even if you change it so many times it won't work until you do.

Comment: Thank you. After setting was struggling for minutes. Restart is required.

Answer (score 2):

Just remember to add quotes into the path if you have a space in your path to java home.
C:\Program Files\java\javaxxx\ doesn't work
but
"C:\Program Files\java\javaxxx\" does.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Ahhhh I see. Just wanted to leave this here since I ended up experiencing the problem with the answer above from Ruchira Gayan.
"JAVA_HOME should be like this
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07"
And I had to wrap the path with quotes. But comment noted. Will come back when I have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

Run the below command in your terminal and restart it.

```
> set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-xx.xx"
```

xx.xx is the java version

Answer (score 1):

The JAVA_HOME should point to the JDK home rather than the JRE home if you are going to be compiling stuff, likewise - I would try and install the JDK in a directory that doesn't include a space. Even if this is not your problem now, it can cause problems in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You are pointing your JAVA_HOME to the JRE which is the Java Runtime Environment. The runtime environment doesn't have a java compiler in its bin folder.
You should download the JDK which is the Java Development Kit. Once you've installed that, you can see in your bin folder that there's a file called javac.exe. That's your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME should point to the home jdk directory and not to jdk/bin directory.

Make sure you have JDK installed in your computer and then you need to set the JAVA_HOME like this:

```
JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk" + "Your current installed version of jdk in your system"
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing java , you have to make two changes in environment variables .

1. `JAVA_HOME` : which should point to jdk installation directory (not including bin) .
2. Path : Which will put the bin on the path  .

if the error is which respect to `JAVA_HOME` , try below :

1. Ensure you have mentioned the directory path correctly  .
2. `JAVA_HOME`  value ending with semicolon could be the ERROR sometimes.If you are not able to remove semicolon from environment, try using cmd as below

   set  JAVA_HOME  = [path of you jdk installation directory ]

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all check if Java is installed on your machine. If not install it from here (Windows): https://www.java.com/download/ie_manual.jsp. If you have the following two folders in your Windows OS: Program Files and Program Files (x86). You can find Java installed folder in one of them depending on your installed java: 64bit or different bit.
2. And to set the environment path, follow this link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIodCpf9E50&ab_channel=TheCodeCity). But before, you should be informed that in my case, java was installed in Program Files (x86). The problem (same with yours) was still there. So, I installed java with 64-bit  which was now installed in Program Files and repeated the same process of new environment setting. The problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **C drive>Program Files>Java>jdk**
2. Then copy the path
3. Go to environment variable and click **"New"**

> **Variable_name =  JAVA_HOME**
>
> **Variable_value = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20**

4. Then click the path and **"Edit"** and Click **"New"**
5. Type this > **%JAVA_HOME%\bin**
   Then click **"OK"**