# ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH

Tags: java

I am currently trying to set up the development environment for minecraft modding in 1.8, but I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66;
>
> Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Well, is there a Java installation at that path?

Comment: Have you tried dropping the semi-colon in your JAVA_HOME value?

Comment: -user1803551 response: Yes, there is

Comment: -Joffrey response: No, I haven't. I will test it right now UPDATE: It did not work :'(

Comment: @JavaDud3 please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315425/error-in-setting-java-home) answer.