# React Native: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I've followed step by step the official [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). I started from a clean linux install and installed everything required as per the "Building Projects with Native Code" tab. I have also read the troubleshooting section. I've already created the project using the terminal.

This is the error when I run `react-native run-android`:

```
    Starting JS server...
    Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

    ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

    Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
    location of your Java installation.

    Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
    Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
    set up your Android development environment:
    https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

It does not find JAVA_HOME because the latest versions of Android Studio don't require Java to be installed in the system. Instead an internal JRE is used.

**Duplicate disclaimer**: I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375542/error-java-home-is-not-set-and-no-java-command-could-be-found-in-your-path). This is not what I want. I know how to set the Java home. I just want to run the react project WITHOUT having to install a separate Java.

Questions:

1. How could I find the internal Java inside the Android Studio folder so that I could point JAVA_HOME to it?
2. If not possible, could I open and run the project inside the `android` folder with Android Studio? How would I refresh this project after modifying the React JavaScript code in the parent folder?

Comment: If your looking for the internal Java (JRE) of the Android Studio, it is located on the folder itself where the android studio is installed. On windows, I've found it on `Android Studio/jre` I'm not sure where to find it on linux.

Comment: @TentenPonce Yep, there it is. Thanks!

Comment: I've added it as an answer so others may use it as a reference. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I have got the issue when im setting up React Native. What I did was Just restarted my PC. Thats it!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I'll answer my own questions and sponfeed my fellow linux users:

1- To point JAVA_HOME to the JRE included with Android Studio first locate the Android Studio installation folder, then find the `/jre` directory. That directory's full path is what you need to set JAVA_PATH to (thanks to @TentenPonce for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48299843/813951)).
On linux, you can set JAVA_HOME by adding this line to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile files`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=<Your Android Studio path here>/jre
```

This file (one or the other) is the same as the one you added `ANDROID_HOME` to if you were following the React Native Getting Started for Linux. Both are hidden by default and can be found in your home directory. After adding the line you need to reload the terminal so that it can pick up the new environment variable. So type:

```
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

or

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

and now you can run `react-native run-android` in that same terminal. Another option is to restart the OS. Other terminals might work differently.

NOTE: for the project to actually run, you need to start an Android emulator in advance, or have a real device connected. The easiest way is to open an already existing Android Studio project and launch the emulator from there, then close Android Studio.

2- Since what `react-native run-android` appears to do is just this:

```
cd android && ./gradlew installDebug
```

You can actually open the nested android project with Android Studio and run it manually. JS changes can be reloaded if you [enable live reload](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#reloading-javascript) in the emulator. Type CTRL + M (CMD + M on MacOS) and select the "Enable live reload" option in the menu that appears (Kudos to @BKO for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42571633))

Comment: for me, it's giving the same error after setting the path of JRE to JAVA_HOME

Comment: do i have to install 'Android SDK Platform 28' and 'Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image' first ? (Zeeshan Ahmad)

Comment: it's still giving the same error after setting the JAVA_HOME in system variables

Comment: I dont see the `/jre` inside the `/home/username/Android/Sdk/`

`build-tools/  patcher/ system-images/  .downloadIntermediates/  platforms/ .temp/
emulator/               platform-tools/         tools/ .knownPackages  skins/  licenses/ sources/`
have I made a mistake during instalation?

Comment: How are we supposed to find the `jre` folder?

Comment: For linux users the jre folder is sometimes located at /opt/ folder, try to find the android studio folder and then the files folder, for me it was /opt/apps/cn.androidgoogle.studio/files/jre/

Comment: If you used snap to install android studio, this is how you export it: `export JAVA_HOME=/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/jre`

Comment: In Android Studio 4.2, I found the JRE path here: File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK

Comment: I didn't understand the solution, which file where it is to paste the directory path??

Answer (score 137):

Windows 10:

**Android Studio  ->  File  ->  Other Settings  ->  Default Project Structure...  ->  JDK location:**

copy string is shown, such as:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
```

In the file locator directory window, right-click on "This PC" ->

**Properties  ->  Advanced System Settings  ->  Environment Variables...  ->  System Variables**

click on the **New...** button under System Variables, then type and paste respectively:

.......Variable name:  **`JAVA_HOME`**

.......Variable value:  **`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`**

and hit the OK buttons to close out.

Some installations may also require **JRE_HOME** to be set in the same way.

To check, open a NEW black console window, then type `echo %JAVA_HOME%`.  You should get back the full path you typed into the system variable.  Windows 10 supports spaces in the filename paths for system variables very well and does not need ~tilde eliding.

Comment: A compelte answer! Make sure to try "echo %JAVA_HOME% in completely new console, as defined in the answer. I did it with an old one and never succeeded.

Comment: My problem was that I didn't have Java installed..... Silly me. Thank you!

Comment: I did need to reboot my Windows machine in order for it to work! Even when echo %JAVA_HOME% gave back the correct file path.

Comment: You may need to restart your PC in order for this changes in 'Environment Variables' to be recognized.

Comment: work for me the jbr folder and not the jre.

Answer (score 29):

I think the right way to find the internal Java used by the Android Studio is to

1. Open Android Studio
2. Go to File->Other Settings->Default Project Structure/JDK Location:
3. and copy what ever string is specified there

This will not require memorising the folder or searching for java and also these steps wil take of any future changes to the java location by the Android Studio team changes I suppose

Comment: Thats a nice way to find it. Saved few mintues.. Thanks

Comment: Android Studio 3.4.1, found at File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs -> 1.8 -> JDK home path

Comment: Android Studio 4.2, found at File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK

Comment: Android Studio Flamingo, found at File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK

Answer (score 16):

I'm using Ubuntu 20 on my machine, I have got the same problem the thing that worked for me was:

```sh
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

you can verify that if the installation was successful or not by:

```sh
java --version
```

you are gonna see something like this in your terminal

```
openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.12+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 11):

It is located on the `Android Studio` folder itself, on where you installed it.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Please add the JAVA_HOME in the System variable no in the user variable

1. Create the Variable name as JAVA_HOME
2. Please use these format in the value box --> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk(version) what you have or downloaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot Manu! No one else mentioned this detail and I just could not get it to work earlier.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this issue by installing `jre`, I have `jdk` already installed but `jre` was not installed.

Answer (score 5):

After adding the environmental variable , please restart the editor. It may save your ton of time.

Answer (score 4):

For those still not able to set JAVA_HOME from Android Studio installation, for me the path was actually not in `C:\...\Android Studio\jre`

but rather in the `...\Android Studio\jre\jre`.

Don't ask me why though.

[Environment variables jre location snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxCVZ.png)

Answer (score 4):

For `ubuntu 16.0+`

You can find the jre folder in android studio on this path `/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/jre`

add the following line in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/jre
```

type

```
sudo nano $HOME/.bashrc
```

or

```
sudo nano $HOME/.bash_profile
```

after this execute the following line to in your `terminal` where you are executing the `npx react-native run-android` to reload the terminal with the new changes

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

or

```
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

Comment: In some cases instead of jre folder there will be jbr folder. In that case replace jre with jbr in folder path.

Answer (score 2):

All I did is go to my project directory from the cmd (command prompt) I typed java -version.it told me what version it was looking for. so I Installed that version and I changed the path to were the jdk of that version was located .

Answer (score 2):

- apparently the system variables were not in sync with the user
  variables
- run as admin on command prompt and set the variable
- i also saw some tips to close the node window and the vscode terminal for
  the variable to take effect

[image]

tip from this site
https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html

```
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_XX"
```

and then

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

Answer (score 2):

For fish users:

1. Open `~/.config/fish/config.fish`;
2. Include line `set JAVA_HOME /home/ronald/Documents/android-studio/jre` and `set PATH $PATH $JAVA_HOME`;
3. Re-open fish terminal.

Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

From Android Studio, go to File, Settings, "Build, Execution, Deployment", Build Tools, Gradle. You should see the path to your JDK there, as visible in the screenshot (tested on Android Studio version 2020.3.1). Set an environment variable called JAVA_HOME containing that path (just google "set an environment variable" and followed by your Operating System name).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

for those who are new to react native development
please set JAVA_HOME like this

instead of
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin
just remove "\bin" from path

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301 after removing \bin

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have java installed
2. your path is wrong

do this:

```
    export | grep JAVA
```

THE RESULT: what java home is set to

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
```

3. follow the path to see if the directories are correct

i did this in my terminal:

```
open /Library
```

then i went to /Java/JavaVirturalMachines
turns out I had the wrong "jdk1.8.0_202.jdk" folder, there was another number... 
4. you can use this command to set java_home

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran this in the command prompt(have windows 7 os):
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre

where what its = to is the path to that jre folder, so anyone's can be different.

Answer (score 1):

what I did to solve this on windows was to go to the environment variables and set the variable name to JAVA_HOME and then set the variable value to C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\openjdk-8u312-b07
[image: I did this first]

then I set the path to C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\openjdk-8u312-b07\bin

[image: and then followed by this]

Answer (score 0):

Guys after fight a lot to find the solution, including pass for many of that articles. I just realized that when you extract the Android SDK it doesn't come inside the folder cmdline-tools/latest and doesn't matter the place that I put the folder, opt/Androd_SDK, $HOME/Android_SDK the sequence of the error were the same. Until I got this error running:

**`➜  bin ./sdkmanager -version`**
Error: Could not determine SDK root.
Error: Either specify it explicitly with --sdk_root= or move this package into its expected location: /**cmdline-tools/latest**/

So, basic the solution was add the content of the SDK zip inside of the folders **cmdline-tools/latest**.

Once you do this, SDK and all the commands will work normally. Just don't forget to finish the configuration, like create the environment of the Android SDK, JAVA and so on.

An awesome article is that one:
https://medium.com/@khairold/setting-up-react-native-on-linux-without-android-studio-a65f3e011bbb

;)

Answer (score 0):

if someone still facing similar issue and looking for an answer for the same? I would like to share the solution which worked for me. And by the way I haven't installed **JAVA JDK/SDK** in order to resolve the issue.

I am using Visual Studio code to develop react-native apps (using nox player for android app testing), I ran into the similar issue:

**Issue:**
$
› Building app...
$
**ERROR: JAVA_HOME** is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
$
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
C:\Users...\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1

**Resolution:** In package.json file I have changed   **"main": "index.js"** to **"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js"** it worked for me.

It would be great if this solution helps anyone, let me know for any additional information.

Comment: Looks like the problem is not the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the following:

1. [Java](https://www.java.com/download/ie_manual.jsp)
2. [JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk18-windows)
3. [JRE](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jre8-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Before you set the path of jre check it's content, in my case the jre folder is empty, but there was a jbr folder.

If you are on a bash terminal, it might take a while to sync with your environmental variables you could easily set it on that terminal

```
export JAVA_HOME='C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr'
```

or

```
export JAVA_HOME='C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use Ubuntu, maybe its helpful this tutorial. You have solution for how to solve error ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH..
There are many solutions found for Windows or Mac OS on internet to resolve this error. I'm using Ubuntu 22.10 kinetic
Solution:
Go to your Android Studio folder, find folder named jbr, copy all content folder, and if you don't have, create a folder named jre and copy in jre folder, all contents from jbr folder. Case close. Error solved.
[java is not set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce47O.png)

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYZPn19qK6E)