# React native :ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH

Tags: react-native

i am new to react native and I am trying to start a new project but  I am getting the following error

```
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

I have set envinonmet variables but I don't know why issue occurring can some one help
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native: JAVA\_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298910/react-native-java-home-is-not-set-and-no-java-command-could-be-found-in-your)

Comment: @Oleksii i folowed that anwer and i have chnaged environment variable and the correct answer in that is following a linux os I have windows

Comment: There is an [answer for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59594243/11410980) as well

Comment: @Oleksii i have updated the envionment variable  as that answer also pls check the new screenshot I added still same errror

Comment: got the answer i just had to restart my computer