# React Native execution error " error Failed to install the app."

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, sdk, java-11

I'm doing a native app for the first time. I correctly configured all the environment variables, installed JDK 11, installed Chocolatey, did everything correctly, but is not running on the emulator or usb device. Could someone help with that?

```
(node:23364) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
info JS server already running.
'"adb"' n�o � reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

    at makeError (C:\Users\ana.tomaz\Downloads\AppVanzeiro\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\ana.tomaz\Downloads\AppVanzeiro\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\ana.tomaz\Downloads\AppVanzeiro\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\ana.tomaz\Downloads\AppVanzeiro\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298910/react-native-java-home-is-not-set-and-no-java-command-could-be-found-in-your

Comment: Doesn't works :( I don't know why

Comment: Did you set you JAVA_HOME path in your bash file?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know the problem

Answer (score 0):

warn No apps connected. Sending "devMenu" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
info Opening developer menu...
metro-file-map: Haste module naming collision: AppVanzeiro
The following files share their name; please adjust your hasteImpl:
* \package.json
* \AppVanzeiro\package.json

Failed to construct transformer:  DuplicateError: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
at setModule (C:\Users\ana.tomaz\Downloads\AppVanzeiro\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\index.js:553:17)
at workerReply (C:\Users\ana.tomaz\Downloads\AppVanzeiro\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\index.js:624:9)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Promise.all (index 17)
at async C:\Users\ana.tomaz\Downloads\AppVanzeiro\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\index.js:395:22
at async DependencyGraph.ready (C:\Users\ana.tomaz\Downloads\AppVanzeiro\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:94:5)
at async Bundler.ready (C:\Users\ana.tomaz\Downloads\AppVanzeiro\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:75:5)
at async IncrementalBundler.ready (C:\Users\ana.tomaz\Downloads\AppVanzeiro\node_modules\metro\src\IncrementalBundler.js:327:5)
at async Server.ready (C:\Users\ana.tomaz\Downloads\AppVanzeiro\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1247:5) {
mockPath1: 'package.json',
mockPath2: 'AppVanzeiro\package.json'

Comment: This should not be an answer for the question, please remove it and maybe add the info on the question instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).