# ionic run android issue

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I occured this issue when running ionic run android cmd 
[image]

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Android SDK? If not, download and install it.
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

Just install it with Android Studio, later you can delete Studio and just leave the SDK (or you can go and find just the SDK but this is easier)

If you already have SDK, go to YourDrive:\Path where you installed\Android\sdk and open **SDK Manager**

You'll see bunch of Android versions, select android 6.0 (API 23), and download/install through SDK manager. It's not bad to install all versions from let's say API 15 to latest.

When building you will need to have Java path set up.

Refer here if you get something like Java Home not found [Error in setting JAVA_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315425/error-in-setting-java-home)