# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 in commande

Tags: android, windows, cordova

I am facing a big problem in the development of my app. Indeed I want to update a cordova plugin with the windows terminal but my computer doesn't want to : [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZDJp.png)

I am using:

- Windows 8.1
- I have JDK 7 and 8 on my computer (D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 and D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25)
- Android Studio with C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre as JDK

I saw a lot of questions but none of the answer satified me. (it mean that I have tried it)

Here a few part of the solution that I've tried :
stackoverflow.com/questions/41542246/cordova-adding-platform-failed-with-an-exception-unsupported-major-minor-version 
stackoverflow.com/questions/37466744/android-studio-continues-to-get-a-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0 
stackoverflow.com/questions/35937875/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-when-rendering-in-android-studio
stackoverflow.com/questions/36146504/android-studio-render-preview-error-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Thank you in advance !

Comment: and cordova version is? if >= 4 then force gradle to use source/targeCompatibility  of java 7

Comment: 5.4.1, thanks, I try this right away !

Edit: by doing that plus doing the answer after It do work ! 
Thanks Both of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to update the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the JDK8 installation directory. Make sure the PATH environment variable points to the same directory too (in this case remember to add a final "/bin" to the path).

If you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi), you will note that 52 means it needs Java SE 8 or superior.

Comment: Okay I see but when I install the JDK 1.8, when I look to the file I see JRE and with JRE it doesn't work .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315425/error-in-setting-java-home

Comment: Try to download the latest JDK from the Oracle [website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). Then try setting the environment variable as follows: JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121. After that, try to add the following path to the PATH environment variable: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin