# Even when I defined the class path, javac is not recognizing it

Tags: java, javac

I am using Windows **7** and **8** in my PC .
I have installed `jdk 7` and created class path for `bin` as it should be.  But when I enter `javac` in the command prompt, it throws an error:

```
 `javac is not recognizing as internal and external`.
```

I have searched for a solution in many websites but nothing could solve my problem.
Would you please help me and suggest where my mistake could be?

Comment: You need to provide bin path to system `path` variable. After doing that, did you close and then start the command prompt? Try doing that. I remember it solved the same issue for me a while ago

Comment: Have you tried restarting console? Also do you mean `path` or `CLASSPATH`?

Comment: _created class path for bin_ No, you need to add the path to Java's bin folder to your system properties.

Comment: [Refer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Comment: http://www.java-forums.org/other-ides/46248-javac-not-recognized-internal-external-command-error.html

http://www.coderanch.com/t/519460/java/java/javac-recognized-internal-external-command

Please try to research your query before posting it on stack overflow good sir.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the environmental variables. Run `sysdm.cpl` from run dialog box to open advanced system properties.

[image]

In the environmental variables, add a new one like in this dialog.

[image]

```
Name :  JAVA_HOME
VALUE:  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\
```

Now edit the value of the `PATH` variable and add `;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\;` at the end of it's value.

[image]

Now, restart your system and you can run java related commands from command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

also set path in your ****System variables*:**`path=c:/..../jdk/bin/;c:/..../JRE/bin;.;`

**user Variables:**`CLASSPATH=c:/..../jdk/bin/;c:/..../JRE/bin;.;`

Answer (score 0):

It is `path` not `classpath` - -till your `bin` folder
and restart `cmd`

Answer (score 0):

Double check your system variable "Path" on System Properties appending %PATH_TO_JDK%\bin. Don't forget to restart the command prompt after.