# Where is jar.exe in Java Development Kit?

Tags: java, windows

I downloaded and installed JDK from [Java SE Development Kit 7 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnes)
in "c:\jdk.1.7.0", set variable path to "c:\jdk.1.7.0", but using command for example:

```
jar xvf ..\src.zip
```

Gives me this error:

```
'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm reading Core Java volume 1 (9th edition). So here it stated to run firstly command:

```
javac -version
```

Then I got that same error. And in bin directory there were no javac.exe too, but I found java.exe and it worked. So does jar.exe is also changed to some another name or it somewhere else? It seems strange that this book is released this year and even names of files do not match in newest version or am I missing something here?..

P.S. I'm using windows 7 64 bit.

using command:

`echo %PATH%`

retuns:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%CommonPr
ogramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Wind
ows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\I
ntel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Fi
les (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2
.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program File
s\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:
\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
```

`%JAVA_HOME%` is set to `C:\jdk1.7.0`

Comment: Surely you know how to search in your OS. If you installed the Java JDK through the installer, [start] -> type "jar.exe", and there it is.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or you will get the solution

Comment: Andrius, the directory you need to add to your PATH environment variable is not "C:\jdk.1.7.0", but "C:\jdk.1.7.0\bin", where "java.exe", "javac.exe", "jar.exe" and the rest of the executables are.

Comment: @AndreiJuan I posted `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to be added in the PATH environment variable

Comment: I just installed JDK 8, and it contains, neither %java_home%/bin/jar nor %java_home%/src.zip so, this question pertains to setting up a java programming environment, which is hardly off topic, but is, sort of goofy ganging up on beginners. oracle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just installed [that same download](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u40-b43/jdk-7u40-windows-x64.exe) on Windows 7 64-bit and I have `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\jar.exe` so you probably do also.

I did notice you installed to a non-standard location, and that the installer gives you two chances to change where it installs.

The first installer window is installing the JDK.  Then a second window comes up and that installs the JRE.

You probably installed the JDK to one place and the JRE to another place.  The JDK will have `jar.exe`, `javac.exe`, and `java.exe` inside its `bin` folder.  The JRE will only have `java.exe` there.

Therefore you should find where you installed the JDK.  The default place is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40` so it is there unless you changed it.

Comment: I just installed JDK 8, and it contains, neither %java_home%/bin/jar nor %java_home%/src.zip

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have the JRE not the JDK.  Check that you installed the right one, then check that you are looking in the right directory on your pc.  You should have both.

Next note that the Path should also include the bin folder.

Comment: My path has bin folder. So link I provided is not jdk?..

Comment: The link sends me to a page that says "Sorry, please accept the license terms" so I cannot download it.  But it does look like it is a JDK just according to the file's name.  Typically if you have java.exe and not javac.exe then you have installed a JRE.  A JDK will install javac.exe and jar.exe

Comment: If theres is no javac.exe in bin folder, you have installed something other than the package in your question.

Comment: @KevinPanko that's right, you must accept the license terms before downloading the JDK distribution. I'll fix link in OP's question.

Comment: I would be more inclined to suspect your PATH variables are incorrect than the download.  Try running "echo %PATH%" in a cmd window and ensure that it contains somewhere "c:\jdk.1.7.0_40\bin"

Answer (score 1):

It is located in the bin folder.
You should link to `c:\jdk.1.7.0\bin`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to set the JAVA_HOME as part of the PATH variable in your Windows system environment. The steps to define the JAVA_HOME variable is here: [How to set java_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2619584/1065197), the only changes for this would be using the `c:\jdk.1.7.0` (the path of your JDK installation) instead of `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6`.

After doing this, edit the PATH variable to look like this

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin; rest of your current PATH variable value
```

To verify if the changes were done correctly, open a cmd and write

```
javac -version
```

You should get the exact version. In my case:

```
javac 1.7.0_40
```

---

> And in bin directory there were no javac.exe too, but I found java.exe and it worked.

Seems that you haven't installed the JDK in the path you think. Look for the real JDK path installation and point the JAVA_HOME system environment variable value to that folder.

Comment: Still get message - 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Andrius paths are fixed. In order that the cmd can take the changes done in system environment variables, you must close it and open it after doing the changes.

Comment: Don't get it what was wrong. Now I reinstalled JDK, and I can see both javac.exe and jar.exe in bin. Anyway thank you everyone.

Comment: My answer explains what you did wrong.