# jar.exe is missing from jdk 8u91?

Tags: java, jar, exe

I got a new computer recently, and I downloaded the JDK 8u91. However, I just found out today, from trying to create a jar file, that I do not have the jar.exe. I thought at first that it wasn't in the Path variables in System > Environment Variables, but that wasn't the problem. When I go to the bin folder for java, the jar.exe is missing. In fact, now that I'm looking again, javac.exe is missing too. I tried downloading jdk 8u91 again, and still no luck. Is this an issue anyone else is experiencing? Everywhere else, the problem seems to only be that people don't have the correct PATH variable or they've only downloaded the JRE and not the JDK.

EDIT >> PLEASE READ: I have searched my entire computer for the jar.exe file. It does not show up in the search. I am looking in all folders, specifically the bin folder, it does not show. Check comments below for the existing .exe's I found in the bin folder. I have already looked at the common answers to similar questions on past posts here on stack exchange before I posted this question. But understand this, the file is still missing.

Comment: I assume this is for x64?

Comment: I installed jdk-8u91-windows-x64.exe locally and jar.exe is present

Comment: I can't tell you where those files may have been installed to, as I'm not running Windows, but I can confirm that they are not missing from the x64 Windows download. I downloaded it and took a peek inside it with Archive Manager; jar.exe and javac.exe are both contained in tools.zip inside jdk-8u91-windows-x64.exe.

Comment: Please have a look at this post below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769332/where-is-jar-exe-in-java-development-kit

Comment: This is for x64. In java > jre1.8.0_91 > bin, the following exe's are present: jabswitch, java, javacpl, java-rmi, javaw, javaws, jjs, jp2launcher, keytool, kinit, klist, ktab, orbd, pack200, policytool, rmid, rmiregistry, servertool, ssvagent, tnameserv, and unpack200.

Comment: Look at the path you are using! You are looking in a JRE installation directory -

Comment: Have you tried looking in: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin`? I very recently did the exact same install and the `jar.exe` and `javac.exe` were definitely included as part of the installation package. My apologies if my previous comment came across as harsh or that I was making fun - I really wasn't - I have surely made this same mistake myself - more than once. Honest - just trying to help -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are inadvertently looking for the Java development tools in a JRE installation directory. I recently installed the same JDK release (`1.8.0_91`) on Windows 8 and the `jar.exe` and `javac.exe` dev tools are **definitely there** (for me, the path is: *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin*).

Double-check and make sure you aren't getting confused and accidentally looking for the files in the JRE directory: *C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91*. I have made that same mistake myself; it can be confusing because both installations share the same root path by default: *C:\Program Files\Java*.

Comment: Ah, my problem was that I was looking in program files x 86. I found it in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin like you said. Strange though, that it didn't show up when I searched my C drive. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Well, the important part is that you got it figured out - glad I could help -

Answer (score 0):

You have to answer twice, about where to install Java. If you want to use your own directories, instead of Windows's, you have to set a separate directory for the JRE, which is what it wants to know, on the second ask. ORACLE's installer should have been done a little less ambiguously.

If you try and answer the same directory, for the jre, as for the jdk, you won't have your jar.exe, or your src.zip folder. They are installed there, until it asks for the destination for the JRE. It might overwrite (remove all) the files in the root directory of the jre folder. In other words, that's the JRE1.8.0_102's bin folder in the root folder of your JDK, now, thanks to the installer.