# I am trying to open Jmeter by the batch file but it gives me a Windows error

Tags: testing, web, jmeter, web-testing

Here is the related error its showing:

> java.exe is not a recognized file as an internal or external command, 
>   operable or external command
>
> errorlevel=9009

Comment: For me, similar error with this message: `Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.` .. my solution posted below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31482515/2162226

Comment: possible duplicate of [javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Answer (score 18):

i was getting the same error on WIndows 8.1(64 bit) and checked java path but it was ok

so i just run my jmeter.bat  with Run as Administrator and it worked for me

Comment: Same with me for windows 7 as well.

Comment: same with win10 x64

Comment: Same here Win7 x86.

Answer (score 8):

Many operating systems have an environment variable such as `PATH` that contains a list of directories (or folders) to be searched when looking for a command to execute. Commands that can be found via the `PATH` are commonly called *external commands*. The program that reads the command line or the batch file and invoked the commands may have a number of built in commands, these are commonly called *internal commands*.

I suggest you examine the `PATH` (or equivalent) set when your *java* command executes from the command line and also when execution is attempted from the batch file. Compare the two and make sure the directory containing your `java.exe` is in the `PATH`.

Answer (score 6):

Does not work with Java 9 beta:

Running:

```
 C:\java -version
```

Gives:

> java version "9-ea"

Just go into command line and run:

```
java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
```

Comment: I had the same problem, but I just removed all the java version check logic from the .bat.

Answer (score 4):

Set the correct Java Path (installed in your system) in Computer -> Advanced System settings -> Environment Variables -> Ok ->  System Variables -> Path

I got the same issue and resolved by following the above steps.

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything, this eventually worked.

Within System Variables:

```
PATH = "C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin"
```

May help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to the path has not been set properly.

Either you can set it in environmental varialables or right click jmeter .bat file,choose edit set the path their,for reference see the jmeter.apache.org user manuals.

Answer (score 0):

For me, my Java path has a space in it and jmeter said it can't find Java

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

.. I looked at the jmeter.sh script and saw it got the path from "Plugin-Ins" .. onward.  I tried just commenting out the `exit` command after that check in the script .. and then I was able to run jmeter.

So apparently the validation logic has a bug, where the error message about ***can't find java*** is in fact **not true** (if Java is indeed set up correctly), so it can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

For windows 8.1 Users:

Error when trying to run jmeter.bat

Error message:

---

Not able to find Java executable or version.  Please check your Java installation. errorlevel=2
Press any Key to continue

---

Resolution:

Right Click jmeter.bat and Run as Administrator.

This worked for me, hope this helps.  Good luck

Comment: This is valid only for you, your JRE was installed as Administrator, that is reason why Jmeter without leveraged privilege can not see it.

Answer (score 0):

Set the correct JM_LAUNCH variable to java.exe

Answer (score 0):

For Windows XP users set Java environment by following the steps here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_environment.htm

Note the path depends on your installed JDK.

And download the file from:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/bin/jmeter.bat

Then replace your `jmeter.bat` with the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Java and still you get this error, please set the `java_home` path to below using typing below command in terminal:

```
export  JAVA_HOME="/Library/InternetPlugIns/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I run many versions of Java.. I modified jmeter.bat.

rem   JM_START - set this to "start" to launch JMeter in a separate window
rem              this is used by the jmeterw.cmd script.
rem
rem   =====================================================

setlocal

rem Minimal version to run JMeter
set MINIMAL_VERSION=1.8.0
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Java80\jre\bin   <<< add This line to jmeter.bat

Answer (score 0):

Copied the JAVA executable from Installed version of Java  from C:\Program FilesJava\jdk1.8.0_191\bin and pasted in the folder where the jmeter bat resides and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Not exactly the same issue but somebody might find it helpful**

Do not double click `jmeter.bat` but instead `ApacheJMeter.jar` in the same directory

For me `jmeter.bat` run but for a brief moment closing almost immediately and not prompting any error. Above workaround allowed me to start working

Answer (score 0):

if JAVA -version shows as blank or empty in the command prompt (CMD) then you need to clear the all java paths in environment variable and again add JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15.1
path= C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15.1\bin;

if you see C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath; like this remove this

and try in new CMD prompt then Java -version will work.