# how to run a java program in command prompt

Tags: java

How to set the path in control panel.I was been trying to change the path in environmental variables but couldn't succeed .The error it was stating was  javac is not recognised as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: windows 8 pre-build os

Comment: The solution to this exact problem is detailed in the very first chapter of the official tutorial: [Getting Started: Common Problems  and Their Solutions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html). See also ["javac is not recognized as an internal or external command"](https://www.google.com/search?q=javac+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command).

Comment: possible duplicate of [javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Answer (score 2):

Ok,here's what you gotta do.
Go to the bin folder where you have java installed. 
If you havent changed the path during installation, it should be this path:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin

Do confirm anyway, as the version may differ & so will the folder name.

Copy this path, including bin.Now,

```
->right click on My computer, go to Properties.
->Select Advanced System Settings
->Click on Environment Variables
->Under System Variables,select path, & then click on edit.
->keep the previous path as it is,add a semicolon after that & paste the path you copied earlier.
```

Click ok/apply & you're done.Now you can run all java commands from any directory on your computer.Once again, dont remove the existing path, you gotta add this new one to the existing one,seperate using semi-colon.