# "Javac not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to run the javac command on my Windows 8 OS, but each time I do, regardless of the directories I've tried, I run into the error from the title.

I'm aware this is a common error and I have tried the advice in links such as these, but it still does not work:
[javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-the-Java-Software-Development-Kit

I'm not sure how relevant this is, but the variable value for my "Path" environmental variable is currently this:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\windows\system32;
C:\windows;
C:\windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin;
```

I have also tried installing the newest version of Java and have restarted my computer; however, I still encounter this issue.

Any advice anyone would have on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PATH variable is wrong. Try updating it to point to your JDK. It almost looks like Java is in there 3 times.

`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`

and

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin`

and

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin;`

This link has a pretty good walkthrough on updating your path appropriately.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#path