# Java program compiling error

Tags: java, command-line, javac

I started learning Java today. I installed jdk8, wrote a simple "Hello World" program and then executed this on command line:

```
c:\java>java hello.java
```

But it shows this error:

> Error: could not find or load main class hello.java

Then I also tried doing this:

```
c:\java>javac hello.java
```

Now it shows:

`'javac' is not recognized ass an internal or external command,operable program or batch file`

How to solve this and compile the Java program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Comment: You have to set jour JAVA_HOME variable to a JDK or add the complete path to `javac`in your commandline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly You need to [Set JAVA_HOME](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html) variable.

You can set `JAVA_HOME` variable in your Windows as

> 1. Right click My Computer and select Properties.
> 2. On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located, for example, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05.

Then you need to compile `.java` file

Compile java program by

```
c:\java>javac Hello.java
```

It generate '.class` file. To run it use

```
c:\java> java Hello  // Not Hello.class
```

Where  `Hello.class` is your class file  name.

Comment: The executable `javac` is part of the JDK. So make sure, that you have the JDK installed and the bin folder on your `PATH`. The `java` executable is part of the JRE, which is a smaller distribution. JRE stands for Java Runtime Environment while JDK is the Java Development Kit.

Comment: @hotzst Please read  OP question carefully, he wrote ` I've installed jdk8`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set JAVA_HOME variable...have a look here  [Setting JAVA_HOME](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html)

**Set JAVA_HOME on a UNIX System**

The JDK software is installed on your computer, for example, at `/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_02`. You can change this location.

*Set JAVA_HOME.*

Korn and bash shells:

```
export JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Bourne shell:

```
JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

C shell:

```
setenv JAVA_HOME jdk-install-dir
setenv PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
Change the permissions to enable you to run the GlassFish ESB Installer.

chmod 755 JavaCAPS.bin
```

**Set JAVA_HOME on a Windows System**

The JDK software is installed on your computer, for example, at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02`. You can move the JDK software to another location if desired.

*Set JAVA_HOME:*

Right click My Computer and select Properties.

On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located, for example, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02`.

also you dont need to write `.java` when you are going to run your program i.e.

```
$javac abc.java

$java abc
```