# 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, war

I need to compress the webApps folder into `webApps.war` in windows command prompt

I have tried:

- directory changed to webApps folder `c:\webApps`
- then `jar -cvf webApps.war`

it produce the error I mentioned in title.. Please suggest any other way.

Comment: Have you Set your classpath?

Comment: No, This is the first time im using jar keyword in command prompt

Comment: Have a look at this. [Setting the Class Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the casspath. It is just the operating system not finding the jar executable.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or?rq=1 (same solution)

Comment: thanks got solution by path setting