# What is the syntax for running a Java program under the command line?

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line

I'm having trouble how to run a NetBeans file right from command prompt.  The program itself works just fine, but when I run it in NetBeans itself, it displays this, which I think is reasonable:

```
    Usage: java Calculator operand1 operator operand2
```

The main problem is when I try to run the java file right from the command line, I'm able to cd to the where the file is located, but I can't access the file right from command line.

```
    src\Chapter10Review>javac Calculator.java
    'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

Any advice as to what the syntax is for accessing a java file from a command line?

Comment: @Reimeus - And update your path :)

Comment: Take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or

Answer (score 2):

First you have to set your JDK's bin folder to your PATH variable. Then the commands are available. 
for running a java you have the options: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a JDK but also check your javac path in Environment variables e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;`.

[See the Java resources](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add **JDK bin** folder path to environment path variable of OS then run your code form the folder where *FileName.java* exists. javac will command will compile your java file and generate byte code in *.class* file then run your class by *java* command. but that class should have main method.

for more info go to this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_environment_setup.htm) or [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)