# Having trouble running javac from command line

Tags: java, cmd, git-bash

I am trying to compile java files using either the command prompt or Git-Bash (running Windows 7) but I am having no luck. I've researched this and followed the simple steps of checking the version of Java I have by running:

```
java -version
```

from the command line and I get "1.8.0_102".

So I went to my PATH variable and appended:

```
;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin
```

I have checked what seems like a thousand times and this is the proper directory, but when I run

```
javac
```

from the command line, I still get the error

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Can anyone huide me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have the JDK as well as the SDK installed? what files are inside the bin folder?

Comment: Does `C:\Progam Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin` actually exist? Also, I imagine that typo is just in your post and not in your actual `PATH` (`Progam` instead of `Program`).

Comment: Try these options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or

Answer (score 0):

Try to set
JAVA_HOME system variable to C:\Progam Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102;

and add %JAVA_HOME%\bin; to your CLASSPATH variable

Then restart the command line and try

Answer (score 0):

It's official, dumbest mistake I've made yet. I wrote

```
Progam Files
```

not

```
Program Files
```