# Could not find or load main class error in command line?

Tags: java, command-line, package

I have an assignment that explicitly states that from the command prompt we are supposed to invoke

```
java GreeterTester John
```

and then print "Hello, John."  when I do that (I've already navigated to the src folder) I get the error

> could not find or load main class GreeterTester

Now I've seen a lot info about how we have to type the package name (we're using the default package) in our command prompt when invoking this command, but what could I put in my code that allows me to simply input

```
java GreeterTester John
```

in command prompt, and it works?  Because we have to use that exact command.

Again, I don't need the package name

Comment: Make sure to include the package name when you run it.  Please show us your code (including the package declaration) and the exact command line you used (cut and paste it to be sure).

Comment: No, what I'm saying is I need to be able to do this without including the package name in command line.

Comment: try with `-cp` commad: `java -cp . GreeterTester`

Comment: You have no package, so don't use a package name. You have not compiled your class, supposedly, so read your instructions again

Comment: I don't know if you need a classpath like @Baby says, but try it http://stackoverflow.com/a/32134203/2308683

Comment: When I attempt to compile using javac GreeterTester.java, I get
   
    "'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: @JesseWiatrak its because you haven't or incorrectly set the environment path variable. Refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Comment: @Baby Try it why? That's the default.

Comment: @EJP urmm. well, in case the default was changed?

Comment: The JDK wasn't in the variables.  I added it and I fixed it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Java is a compiled language. You must first compile your code with `javac GreeterTester.java`

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/unix.html#unix-2b

Comment: Hilarious... not the answer, but if that was the problem.

Comment: Looks like it probably was. See the OP's second comment.

Comment: Ooohyeah. one-up for you then!