# "javac is not recognised" after setting the path

Tags: javac

I already set the path in advanced settings. but when i compile a program it says

> javac is not recognised.. 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Comment: Removed tags from title; grammar.