# I can't get my Command Prompt to read javac commands after using the Path solution. (Windows 8.1 64bit)

Tags: java, windows, path

I keep getting the reading:

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

Here is my current Path with java included:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;
C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin
```

Not sure what I am missing. I have restarted my computer as well. Any suggestions? To be clear I am a first semester CS Student with 0 experience, so I might not understand certain terminology.

Comment: Are you sure javac is in *JRE* path? It’s a part of *JDK*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Answer (score 2):

You have included **JRE**:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin
```

You must include **JDK** like:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin
```

Comment: The OP would need to include `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin`, not `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, yes, you are correct. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your path includes `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin` - it's JRE (runtime). `javac` is a program from JDK (development kit). JRE is a part of of JDK, not vice versa.

Download and install JDK (or check does it exists something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin`)