# 'appletviewer' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, applet

> ```
> C:\Users\ms536\Desktop\java>appletviewer awt_ex.java
> 'appletviewer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> ```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: ok. and your actual question is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Answer (score 10):

I can think of three possible explanations for this:

1. You may have not set the command search path (`$PATH`) correctly.  This is a common for people who are new to Java;  see [javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/)
2. You may be trying to use `appletviewer` in Java 11 or later.  This won't work.  Applet support was deprecated in Java 9, and was removed entirely in Java 11; see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8200146.
3. You may have installed a JRE rather than a JDK.  The `appletviewer` is (was) only available in JDK installations.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install java 8 , set the path and then try to run the program again
Because applets are now obsolete and not in use any more. So their support has been removed in the latest versions