# Javac not being recognized in command prompt

Tags: java, javac

I have reinstalled java, alongside other files needed to be downloaded on oracle. I then set the Path in environment variables, and it is even recognized in the command prompt when i type in 'set path". But whenever i try to use javac to try and command a code out of subline, it wont recognize it. What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

It means javac is not on path. You should try complete path to javac

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `JAVA_HOME/bin` folder in your machine's PATH to solve this error. If you are using the same `CMD` window after setting the `PATH` variable you need to close it and then open `CMD` again and try. If you did that, double-check if the `JAVA_HOME/bin` folder is available in the PATH environmental variable by typing `echo %PATH%`. And if it is there check the `JAVA_HOME/bin` path is correct. If the path is not there go through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8518438). It describes everything perfectly that you need to know and you need to do. Hope this helps you!