# Remove bad entry in PATH from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, android-studio

I set PowerShell as my default terminal in Android Studio settings after that I modified my PATH from inside the Android Studio Terminal (PowerShell) like:

```
$env:PATH = $env:PATH + "C:\SomePath"
```

However I ommited the **";"** at the beginning of **"C:\SomePath"** by doing this now my last entry in the path looks like **"C:\LastEntryC:\SomePath"** what is wrong.

How to modify this entry from PowerShell to have **"C:\LastEntry;C:\SomePath"**?

I tried to change the PATH variable from the Windows Control Panel but it's different, It seems that the PATH in android studio is local to the IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran your command against my own path variable.

```
$env:PATH = $env:PATH + "C:\SomePath"
```

Which gave, the tail of my path, the following.

```
...C:\Program Files (x86)\NmapC:\SomePath
```

To correct i used a replace command on the path environment variable. The first \ has to be escaped.

```
$env:PATH = $env:PATH -replace "C:\\SomePath",";C:\SomePath"
```

Upon further reflection a simpler Idea to this would be just to use `-join`

```
$env:PATH = $env:PATH,"C:\SomePath" -join ";"
```

Comment: I like your short and clear answer! Any ideas why getting the path from my PowerShell terminals (IDE & System) was not the same?

Comment: Not completly sure but it might be scope related: See other post about user and system environment variables. You might have been working with both. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477660/what-is-the-difference-between-user-variables-and-system-variables