# Gradle Command Not Found

Tags: java, angularjs, gradle, jboss

So I recently made the jump from `Ant` to `Gradle` and it is wonderful. However, I am having some issues getting gradle to run from a server.

I have a script that I can manually execute to run all of my gradle tasks to build my app. This works perfectly when I am logged into the machine. The problem is that I am now trying to kick off that script for a nightly build. And in order to kill two birds with one stone I launched a `JBoss` server with a custom service to call that script nightly and call the script with a specific hooks from GitHub.

Does anyone know what the difference would be between calling the script when I am logged into the machine and having a server (which I started when I was logged in) call the same script?

The only information I get from the console:

```
    gradle: command not found
```

Comment: At the first glance it looks like your environment (path variable?) is different. But what you are trying to do sounds a little bit strange to me - or I just didn't get it. Do you try to use jboss as a CI server?

One more hint. Try to use the gradle wrapper (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) so you are more independent from your environment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As say @TobiSH First of all check your environment `echo $GRADLE_HOME && echo $PATH`

Path to `gradle` can be setting up only for your user and not for all system

`.profile` or `.bashrc` instead of `/etc/environment` (for linux systems)

Second option is try to use [gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)

```
$ gradle wrapper
```

to be more independent from your environment

You can read more about different user and system variable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477660/what-is-the-difference-between-user-variables-and-system-variables) (windows)

For ubuntu and other linux based systems [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4667/where-to-declare-environment-variables)