# Can't run artisan commands on cmd because of parse error

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php, laravel-artisan

The error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' , expecting
>   identifier  or variable  OR '{' OR '$' in
>   c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\artisan on line 31.

First of all, I haven't made this project but it was running with no problems(it still seems to run ok but I can't run any artisan commands!!). The version of laravel it was running was 5.2 while php was 5.4.31 as it is shown on cmd, although when I run phpinfo() function on xampp it shows 5.6.23. Why is that?

I haven't changed one bit of the code. It started doing this after I had been trying to create another project of laravel in a local folder. Every time I deleted it and installed it again, it kept downloading it on laravel 5.0. What can I do?

I can't update php version because there are a lot of projects that are running on the server and I am afraid I will mess it up.

Comment: Depends on your environment. Your local hosted version of Laravel is probably different to your system version. How are you serving your app?

Comment: The app that is not working was running from xampp. My project was running locally with artisan serve

Comment: Exactly, so your system (CMD) version of php does not meet the requirements. You will need to upgrade it to >5.5.

Comment: The thing is that it was playing perfectly until something changed in the environmental variables when I uninstalled and reinstalled my project!! Also, I already told you the reason why I can't upgrade to a newer version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up the `artisan` file, you will see line 31 is doing this:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
```

`::class` is [only available from PHP 5.5 onwards](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) so, tl;dr, you can't run laravel 5.2 on PHP 5.4.

So to solve this, in your windows environment, simply point `php` to run on your php 5.6 variant and that should solve it.

Comment: How do I do this? From environment variables->user variables? To what do I change the path? Now it has C:\Users\....\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin

Comment: Plenty of tutorials online: https://www.google.com.sg/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=xampp%20php%20environment%20variable

Comment: I added the path where php.exe is but still nothing changed, php artisan command on cmd shows the same error.

Comment: Should I put it in User variables or System variables? Nevermind, it doesn't play either way... HELP?

Comment: Try closing your command prompt and start another new cmd window - that should usually help :) [See here for differences between user variables & system variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477660/what-is-the-difference-between-user-variables-and-system-variables)

Comment: Ok, I did it! Thank you very much all!