# Git is not recognised in Visual Studio Code

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code

The issue is Visual Studio Code does not recognise the ___ as they say "out of the box git" in their editor...

So I have installed Git five times, reinstalled Visual Studio Code five times, restarted the computer every time plus checked all the environment variables and have been googling the problem for two days...

Nothing is solving this problem other than a fresh install of Windows on the computer. I don’t have any clue where to turn to next...

Images of the issue...

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Third]

Comment: The entry in your settings file has a green line under it, what message does it give?

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me! It says:

"Unknown configuration setting.."

Comment: Likely canonical (2015, 36 answers, and 221 votes): *[Visual Studio Code cannot detect installed Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29971624/)*.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [provide some text](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50639459/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check your *[System variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows/72341522#72341522)* environment variables and make sure that you have your Git path (*C:\Program Files\Git\bin*) added in the *path* environment variable.

Comment: Thank. It worked for me. I added git path (C:\Program Files\Git\bin) into System Environment and restart Vscode. I don't understand why I am using it normally then I have this problem.

Comment: There is also *[What is the difference between user variables and system variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477660/what-is-the-difference-between-user-variables-and-system-variables)*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are setting the `git.path` setting in your **workspace settings** as opposed to your **user settings**.

As detailed in the [Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-and-security), for security reasons a number of settings that relate to external executables such as Git must be placed in **user settings** (otherwise you could, for example, clone a project that specifies a malicious executable instead of the actual Git executable in the project's workspace settings, thus causing you trouble).

If that Git path is indeed correct, then moving the setting to the **user settings** should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
The same issue is in user settings.. 

The problem is that git is not recognised in VS code

Comment: Positive that is the git path 

C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe

But just to make sure I have tested both ways multiple time..
The concern is that VS code does not recognise git..
As you can see in the other 2 images above

Thanks for the tip I wish this error was that simple though

Comment: Curious... Where did you install git from? Also, should have asked before, but can you use git on the command line?

Comment: I installed it from the same site that vs code says they get their git from
https://git-scm.com/

Yes git works in all terminals =)

Comment: A bit of a shot in the dark but some comments on github issues have suggested that writing the path in unix style (forward slashes instead of backwards ones) works for some people

Comment: That might work once git is recognised by vs code.
Thanks for the help though I really appreciate it