# BiqQuery detected on windows command prompt but not on Bash

Tags: gcloud, git-bash, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk, bq

I've installed Cloud SDK on my windows 10 machine and I'm able to run commands like "gcloud", "gsutil" and "bq" on my command prompt. However, when I run "gsutil" or "bq" on Bash, this is the error I'm getting.

`$ bq`

`bash: bq: command not found`

Then I added this location to PATH `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin`, and afterwards I seem to be able to call `gsutil` and `bq` using `gsutil.cmd` and `bq.cmd`. But of course, I'd prefer calling bq / gsutil directly.

Has anyone has this problem before? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I found one possible solution!

1. In Bash, go to the root bash folder by typing `cd`
2. Type `touch .bashrc`
3. write `alias bq="bq.cmd"` or `alias gsutil="gsutil.cmd"` or both
4. Press `Esc` and type `:qa` and `Enter` to save and exit

This tells Bash to remember bq as invoking bq.cmd, hence now I can invoke bq anywhere -- as far as I know.

If anyone has a better suggestion, please let me know! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the bash session itself, check what `echo $PATH` returns. It should inherit the path that was defined on Windows.

So open a new CMD session, and:

- make sure the `%PATH%` does include `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin`,
- then call `C:\path\to\Git\bin\bash.exe` to open a bash session

`bq` should work in such a shell session.

Comment: Hi VonC, yes %PATH% does include the path you specified, and yes I am able to perform your second step. But shouln't Bash be able to launch bq / gsutil from any folder I open Bash in?

Comment: @johnconnor92 not if the Cloud SDK path is declared in the PATH from User variables instead of the system environment variables (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16305526/6309). A contextual menu in an explorer might open a session with only the system variables. Or at least try and reboot first, to see if the issue persists.