# Python virtual environment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables, virtualenv, python-venv

Is there such a thing as virtual environment variables in Python?

To be very specific, I understand there are user environment variables and system environment variables but I want to know if there are env vars specific to Python and especially virtualenv specific.

If yes, where are these variables kept?

Comment: Does "specific to Python" mean [controlling python by setting them](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables)? Or do you want to set some when activating a venv?

Comment: Rather not, but you can simulate them with user/system variables. E.g. if you want to set MY_VAR for two virtual envs "ABC" and "XYZ", you can set two different variables "ABC_MY_VAR" and "XYZ_MY_VAR", and from python you can check from which environment you run using `import sys; import os; print(os.environ[sys.real_prefix + '_MY_VAR'])`

Comment: Enlighten me; what's the difference between a user environment variable and a system environment variable, aside from where they are ultimately defined? (Is this a Windows distinction?)

Comment: @chepner : System environment variables are globally accessed by all users.
User environment variables are specific only to the currently logged-in user.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477660/what-is-the-difference-between-user-variables-and-system-variables
I only use Windows, so I am not sure if it is Windows specific.

Comment: @ivvija: I want to set some when activating a venv.

Comment: The venv activate scripts (`.venv/bin/activate`, `.venv\Scripts\activate`, ...) can be modified to add variables, but I recomment a `.env` file in your project dir. More explicit and not hidden in some script. See [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/). Also supported by many other tools.

Comment: @Cervelle Ok. In Unix, there's no strict definition. Environment variables are either inherited from a parent process, or added to the current environment for children processes to inherit. There's no strong distinction between system and user, only acknowledgment of when the variable is first added to an environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, there are no environment variables specific to a virtual environment in python. (at least from a native point of view)

However as mentioned by others there are several ways to work around this:

1. By creating a ".env" file containing the variables in the project.
2. By modifying the activate script and adding variables.
3. By defining os environment variables with a specific syntax (prefix or suffix) and use it depending of the current env.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the project environment variables in a `.env` file and load them with [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/). E.g.

1. Install `python-dotenv`

```bash
$ pip install python-dotenv
```

2. Create a file `.env` with your environment variables

```ini
FOO=bar
PORT=8000
```

3. Load variables with `python-dotenv`

```py
import os


def sample():
    print(os.environ.get("PORT"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from dotenv import load_dotenv

    load_dotenv(".env")
    sample()
```